# How to make column data from row data relationship in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, relationship

I have some table like this in codeigniter query

**regist_header** with column:
id,
request_id,
regist_number,
created_date,
etc

and have table for activity regist_header, like this

**document_status** with column: regist_header_id, status, date

this is my regist_header
[regist_header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWqpj.png)
and this is my document_status [document_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hsXh.png)


from that relationship, i wanna make data like this in one row each data


id | request_id | registration_number | submit_date | approve_date | activation date

Thankyou

Comment: Please post you sample table data in textual form and not as images. Also post your attempted query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the document_status data, it looks like you have multiple entries for the same status. So do you want to show latest records or earliest records? Based on the latest records, that query could help:

```
select rh.id, rh.request_id, rh.registration_number, ds.submit_date, ds.approve_date, ds.activation_date
  from regist_header rh
  left 
  join (
        select regist_header_id,
               max(case when status = 'submit' then max_date end) as submit_date,
               max(case when status = 'approve' then max_date end) as approve_date,
               max(case when status = 'activation' then max_date end) as activation_date
          from document_status ds
         group by regist_header_id
       )ds
    on rh.id = ds.regist_header_id
```

Comment: This is very clear, i just need combine with query builder. Thanks